# The location of the html output from the_post_thumbnail();

Tags: post-thumbnails, html

So I added the_post_thumbnail(); so I can add images through the featured image area in the wordpress.

I am trying to add schema to the output since it isn't working by just wrapping the_post_thumbnail(); in a span.

I am curious where the html output is defined in the files?

Answer (score 1):

Use the filter `post_thumbnail_html` ([source](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_post_thumbnail/)):

```
function wpse_195454_post_thumbnail_html( $html ) {
    if ( $html )
        $html = '<span class="wrap">' . $html . '</span>';
    return $html;
}

add_filter( 'post_thumbnail_html', 'wpse_195454_post_thumbnail_html' );
```